# Unable to compare datetime variables in stored procedure sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to compare two datetime variables in a stored procedure sql server.
In the below code snippet `@createdDate` is taken as user input and then comparing with a column of type datetime. I am unable to check the ''='' property

```
set @sqlquery = 'Select
            v.*,
            vsc.vidhanSabhaConstituencyName, where 1=1 '

set @sqlquery = @sqlquery +'AND v.createdBy ='''+cast(@createdBy as nvarchar(100))+''''

if(@VoterIdNumber is not null)
set @sqlquery = @sqlquery+'AND v.voterIDNumber= '''+@VoterIdNumber+''''

if(@createdDate is not null)
set @sqlquery = @sqlquery+'AND v.dataIsCreated = '''+cast(@createdDate as varchar(100))+''''
else
set @sqlquery = @sqlquery+'AND v.dataIsCreated= '''+cast(getdate() as varchar(100))+'''' 

Execute sp_Executesql @sqlquery
```

I've tried casting and converting the `@createdDate` variable without success.
It works with other operators like `>=` or `<=` but not with `=` .

Help is appreciated

Comment: Probably not working with `=`  because the value is accurate to the second perhaps?. Better use only the date part if you do not need accuracy to the second.

Comment: Did you try `PRINT @sqlquery;`? That might make it obvious why the match isn't happening.

Comment: when using `sp_executesql`, the idea is that you **pass in the values as parameters**, not that you concatenate everything; you should be doing something like `exec sp_executesql @sqlquery, N'@createdDate datetime, @createdBy nvarchar(200)', @createdDate, @createdBy;`, with things like `set @sqlquery = @sqlquery + 'AND v.createdBy = @createdBy '`

Comment: Thanks for your input Marc , but i need to concatenate strings and values because there are many values that needs to be checked for null. When I try to apply '=' directly , I get the below error  "The data types nvarchar and date are incompatible in the add operator."

Comment: Why are you converting createdDate to a string?  You shold pass it from c# as a DataTime.  You also need to convert the DateTimes to a Date with no hours, minutes seconds (midnight) so the dates compare.

Comment: You can still follow Marc's advice. `if @param is not null set @sql += N' and column = @param';` You can add `@param` to the param declaration and parameters list with no consequence. We're not telling you this to hear ourselves talk; SQL injection is a real danger, and ignoring it is careless and likely punishable. Please read [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/) and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/) in full...

Comment: I fully agree with Marc and Aaron , this is wrong practice and I am going to change the query as specified .
Thanks a lot Marc and Aaron

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have modified my stored procedure as suggested by Marc and Aaron.
Below is my code snippet .

```
set @sqlquery = N'Select
            v.*,
            vsc.vidhanSabhaConstituencyName,
            lsc.lokSabhaConstituencyName,
            wc.wardName.....''

SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + N' AND v.createdBy = @createdBy';
        If @VoterIdNumber Is Not Null SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + N' AND v.voterIDNumber = @VoterIDNumber';

        If @createdDate Is Null SET @createdDate = null
                SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery + N' AND CONVERT(date, v.dataIsCreated) = @createdDate';

                EXEC sp_executesql
    @sqlquery,
    N'@createdBy varchar(50), @VoterIDNumber varchar(50), @createdDate date',

                @createdBy = @createdBy,
                @VoterIDNumber = @VoterIdNumber,
                @createdDate = @createdDate
```

Answer (score 0):

i just give u an example,here SMSDATE is datetime ,it gives output for me.try to implement the same logic in your procedure

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_1 WHERE  CONVERT(varchar, SMSDATE,110)  = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(),110)
```

Comment: not working as my procedure is based on query concatenation

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't use `cast` on a `datetime`. Use `convert` instead so you can specify an appropriate format for the result. The output of `cast` is going to depend on your region settings. For instance, when I run `select cast(getdate() as varchar(100));` on my instance of SQL Server, I get the following:

```
Mar 15 2018  9:37AM
```

The precision of this value is obviously far more limited than that of a `datetime`: any two `datetime` values that happen to occur within the same minute will be converted to the same string. So if I try to use `=` to compare this value to values stored in a `datetime` field of a table, I'll find that the comparison will fail if the stored value has a nonzero seconds or milliseconds component.

If you must convert a `datetime` to a string, use [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) with the style parameter that is most appropriate for how you're going to use it. For instance, if I run `select convert(varchar(100), getdate(), 126);`, I get:

```
2018-03-15T09:43:42.240
```

This is a much better choice of format for a date/time literal because it doesn't discard any data from the original value (like how my first example lost its seconds and milliseconds components) and is usable regardless of your region settings.

All that said, Marc Gravell had a very important comment on your question: you should be passing in a string of parameters rather than trying to concatenate everything. This will work even if the number of parameters that you actually want to include in your predicate is variable. For instance, consider the following example:

```
create table dbo.Test (A int, B datetime);
insert dbo.Test values (1, getdate());
go

declare @A int;
declare @B datetime;

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * from dbo.Test where 1=1';

if @A is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' and A = @A';
if @B is not null
    set @sql = @sql + ' and B = @B';

print @sql;
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@A int, @B datetime', @A = @A, @B = @B;
```

If I run this query as written, with `@A` and `@B` both left at null, then the value of `@sql` will simply be:

```
select * from dbo.Test where 1=1
```

If I set `@A` to 1, then I get:

```
select * from dbo.Test where 1=1 and A = @A
```

If I also set `@B` to a non-null value, then I get:

```
select * from dbo.Test where 1=1 and A = @A and B = @B
```

This is much easier to understand and maintain, and it's much safer as well. All the string concatenation you're doing in your original query is just begging for a SQL injection attack. You can either read up on this topic at [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), or simply consider what will happen to your query if I do something like:

```
set @createdBy = 'Admin''; drop table dbo.v; --';
```

This should be enough to go on, but feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for your input Joe. I am going to try that

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

declare @date datetime
set @date = '2018-03-13'
select  * from user_tbl where cast(createddate as date) = cast(@date as date)
here, @date should be your sp date parameter